# SQL print table1 entries containing table2 entries

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Firstly, I apologize if this already exists but I have tried multiple different searches all over google and here and found nothing that helps.

I have a database 'database1' and two tables, 'table1' and 'table2'.
table1 has 3 columns: URL, DateTime and VisitCount.
table 2 has one column: keyword.

The URLs in table 1 are as they appear in the csv file they came from, just standard http URLs.
Table 2 has keywords of shopping websites such as 'amazon' and 'ebay'.

I am using netbeans. My table currently shows all results from table1. When the user clicks 'Shopping' the table should filter all of the results to show only those which contain the results from table2 in them somewhere. The table and buttons all work, it is just the query I am having trouble with.

I have tried:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE URL LIKE keyword
```

also:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE URL LIKE (SELECT * FROM table2)
```

and various slight variations, none of which work. I'm not even sure if it is possible to do this?

Thankyou very much in advance.

Comment: *When the user clicks 'Shopping' the table should filter all of the results to show only those which contain the results from table2 in them somewhere*. **Does your table2 contain the keyword "Shopping"?** If not, how would associate the word **"Shopping"** with "Amazon" or "ebay". You either need to map the keyword with category OR pass "amazon" or "ebay" as parameter.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer. The thing they click is just a button that says "shopping" on it. The aim is for them to click this button which will then use some java code to execute a query to check if any URL in table1 contains any of the words listed in table2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT table1.*
FROM table1, table2
WHERE table1.URL LIKE CONCAT('%', table2.Keyword, '%')
```

Comment: Thankyou so  much! I've wasted days trying to figure it out. Many thanks!

Comment: Enjoy :) but its performance could pretty poor with large tables. Also, you will get duplicates if there are duplicate keywords (however it can be resolved with some small changes to the query).

Answer (score 1):

try concat your search string (keyword) with "%" before and after it:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE URL LIKE CONCAT("%",keyword,"%")
```